# connect to FileMaker Server with pyodbc

Tags: pyodbc, filemaker, freetds, unixodbc

I have a FileMaker db running on FileMaker Server 14 on a Mac Mini and I'm trying to get at it with pyodbc. It's not going well.

First, what works:

```
telnet 192.169.19.3 2399
ssh Name@192.169.19.3
tsql -H FM-Server -p 2399 -U Name -P pwd
```

One weird thing about that last one is that it gives me a seconds counter:
`1`
`2`
not a prompt, although I can still type commands in. I'm not sure what that means and couldn't find any info about it.

Now, what doesn't work:

```
tsql -LH 192.169.19.3
tsql -LH FM-Server
isql FM-Server Name pwd
```

No listed info for the FileMaker Server, isql gives me `[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect` which is just so helpful you know

One issue is that at this point I've sort of forgotten if I should be using FM ODBC or FreeTDS as my driver in pyodbc, luckily neither of them work:

```
>>> c = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={FreeTDS};DSN=FM-Server;UID=Name;PWD=pwd")  
pyodbc.Error: ('08001', '[08001] [unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unable to connect to data source (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')  
>>> c = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={FileMaker ODBC};DSN=FM-Server;UID=Name;PWD=pwd")  
pyodbc.Error: ('08S01', '[08S01] [unixODBC][FileMaker][FileMaker ODBC] Failed to connect to listener (2) (65535) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

Giving it just the DSN freezes the window. Here's my configs:

odbc.ini | /usr/local/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.4/etc/odbc.ini

```
[FM-Server]
Driver = FreeTDS
Host = 192.169.19.3
ServerName = FM-Server
UID = Name
PWD = pwd
Port = 2399
```

odbcinst.ini | /usr/local/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.4/etc/odbcinst.ini

```
[ODBC Drivers]
FileMaker ODBC = Installed
FreeTDS = Installed 

[FileMaker ODBC]
Driver = /Library/ODBC/FileMaker ODBC.bundle/Contents/MacOS/fmodbc.so
Setup  = 

[FreeTDS]
Description = FreeTDS
Driver = /usr/local/Cellar/freetds/1.00.9/lib/libtdsodbc.0.so
Setup = /usr/local/Cellar/freetds/1.00.9/lib/libtdsodbc.0.so
UsageCount = 1
```

freetds.conf | /usr/local/Cellar/freetds/1.00.9/etc/freetds.conf

```
[FM-Server]
    host = 192.169.19.3
    port = 2399
    tds version = 8.0
```

Any info is much appreciated and shout to the resources [here](http://www.cerebralmastication.com/2013/01/installing-debugging-odbc-on-mac-os-x/), [here](https://www.acloudtree.com/how-to-install-freetds-and-unixodbc-on-osx-using-homebrew-for-use-with-ruby-php-and-perl/), and elsewhere for helping me get even this far.

Comment: You definitely need to use the FileMaker ODBC driver. FreeTDS is for working with Microsoft SQL Server and Sybase.

Comment: Thanks, I'll update this question when I get back to the testing machine, but, in the meantime, do you know how I can point pyodbc to the ODBC Driver Manager application from http://www.odbcmanager.net/?

Comment: The ODBC Manager application is presumably just a convenient way of updating the contents of the ODBC .ini files. You would use it to create a DSN entry that uses the "FileMaker ODBC" driver, and that DSN would be written to odbc.ini. Then pyodbc would use that DSN to connect, e.g. `cnxn = pyodbc.connect("DSN=MyFileMakerDSN;")`. Note that when using a DSN for your connection, only the DSN *name* is required in the connection string since the other properties (Driver, Server, Database, ...) are defined in the DSN entry (in odbc.ini).

Answer (score 4):

I was able to solve this with the following, slightly abbreviated

`brew uninstall freeDTS
brew uninstall unixODBC
pip uninstall pyodbc`

re-installed pyodbc with ActualTech's installer (not sure if necessary): http://www.actualtech.com/python-osx-odbc.php

switched my odbc.ini to read "Driver=FileMaker ODBC" instead of "Driver=freeTDS" but given the code I actually ran I'm not that that's necessary:

`python
import pyodbc
c = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={FileMaker ODBC};SERVER=192.169.19.3;PORT=2399;UID=Name;PWD=pwd")`

and magically that worked. idk man